# How to Assign Variable from Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable

I am trying to create a variable to return which indicates whether a thread was successful in doing its job or not - however, it requires the variable be final which means it cannot be re assigned.

What is needed in order to facilitate something such as this

```
public static void sendFeedbackEmail(final String user, final FeedbackRating rating,    final String feedbackText, final EmailAddress emailToSendTo) {
    if (rating != null && !StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(user)) {
        boolean result = false;
        Thread emailSender = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                feedbackText = (StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(feedbackText)) ? "N/A" : feedbackText;
                String message = FEEDBACK_MESSAGE.replace("?", rating.getValue())   + user + " Text: " + feedbackText;
                String emailAddress = (emailToSendTo == null) ? USER_FEEDBACK_EMAIL_ADDRESS : emailToSendTo.getValue();
                try {
                    sendVimbaMessage(user, emailAddress, message);
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    result = false;
                }
                result = false;
            }
        });
        emailSender.setDaemon(true);
        emailSender.start();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with returning a boolean? Also, you appear to be trying to return false from a method with a void return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do with a Runnable:

```
public class YourClass implements Runnable{

    private boolean yourVariable;

    public YourClass(boolean v){
       yourVariable = v
    }

    public void run(){
       .....
    }

    ........

}
```

And when creating the thread, say you have a variable which is not final:

```
boolean nonFinalVariable = true;
Thread t = new Thread(new YourClass(nonFinalVariable));
```

Answer (score 0):

How I get around this issue myself is by creating a class dedicated to sharing variable among threads. I do this for my GUI Programs, I got one thread reading from devices over socket and then my GUI window.

```
public class SharedVar{
    private int int1;
    private boolean isThreadADone;

    public SharedVar(){
        int1 = 0;
        isThreadADone = True;
    }

    public void setInt1(int value){
        int1 = value;
    }
    public int getInt1(){
        return int1;
    }
    public void setIsThreadADone(boolean value){
        isThreadADone = value;
    }
    public boolean isThreadADone(){
        return isThreadADone;
    }

}
```

when you do this. U must hand this class to everything u want values to be shared with.

```
SharedVar globalVar = new SharedVar();
```

All threads needs this "globalVar" for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than 1 ways to achieve this.

1) You can pass a pojo which has a boolean variable as field which you can get/set even if your pojo reference is declared as final.
2) You can use Callable instead of Runnable to [return status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516383/how-to-return-object-from-callable).

Another way would be to update status in a table or file, to indicate error failure.